# can't open steam in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: steam, 17.10

Steam does not work after version 17.10 and I installed by deb package and do not want to open in ubuntu anymore 17.04 worked but in ubuntu 17.10 does not work

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Have you installed it through the terminal? If so, try uninstalling the steam related packages again with Synaptic Package Manager and go to the Steam website and download the package from there: http://store.steampowered.com/about/

You might also have to delete the Steam folder in your home folder home/.steam so Steam can create a fresh one.

Tried a hell of a lot of things and this simply worked without problems as it should be. Appartently the version in the software depository is outdated or whatever? No clue, I'm a noob.